# How to allow empty or a string validated by a regex in JOI?

Tags: node.js, joi

I am to pass a vat value. The validation should allow saving it in the db if it is empty or passes the given regex of a certain country.

```
.when('country_code', {
                is: 'AT',
                then: Joi.alternatives([
                    Joi.string().allow(''),
                    Joi.string().regex(/(AT)?U[0-9]{8}/)
                ])
            })
```

This what I have achieved till now but it isn't working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what you are looking for:
`Joi.string().regex(/(AT)?U[0-9]{8}$/).allow('')`